# Render Result doesn't match camera view

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, camera

I'm new to blender and am having issues rendering my final image. I have already used ctrl + alt +numpad0 to get the right camera position and angle. But when I hit F12, the render result does not match the camera view.[image: camera view]. I have tried several things and my render results just keeps coming up as completely different. I don't think I have any key frames, and everything should be on the right layer? I just wish to render a still frame, no animation.

[image: render view, not done rendering]

UPDATE: Render finished and the output is still completely different from my viewport and camera.
[image]

Even using viewport render does not work[image]

[Blender file is here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rCEYSpHzeMBgB-TepyGhtX6sycWUclLU?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi. The second image (render output) shows only 8 tiles. It's hard to tell if the view of the render really matches the camera's view or if there are objects missing/not rendered. The estimated time of over 8 hours for the whole image is very long for the simple looking shading. You can reduce the number of samples (see Sampling -> Render on the first image) from 128 to 4 to do a quick check of what is actually rendered.

Comment: Hi, update includes final render. I have even tried to use the viewport render and the output is just that grey image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objects scale and clipping start and end are all off. But that didn't help. I did get a render that matched if you just apply the cloth and subdivision surface. Even leaving everything else alone.

Comment: Hi, I thought I did apply them. i have tried selecting and unselecting my cloth and subdivision surfaces, but that causes the cloth to fall our of place.

Comment: Sorry, yes nevermind, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The *"real"* cause of the issue, is the subdivision modifier:

[image]

As the subdivision levels does not match in *viewport* and *render*, the cloth cash is not valid when rendering.

Turn the *render subdivision levels" to 1 and that will be ok.